# Solve multivariable nonlinear equation with mixed constraints?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

How do I solve a

- multivariable ($x_1$ to $x_m$)
- nonlinear (in this case a quadratic)

objective function with mixed

- (equality (my Sum) and
- inequality (bounded variables)
- in this case linear

constraints?

Is Lagrange an option here? (I know Lagrange can handle the equality constraints, but in combination with inequality constraints?)

Any help is apprecciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with slack variables ?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, but if this is the way to go, I'll learn the technique. A quick google search (and the wiki article) said thats its required to turn inequality to equality constraints, sounds promising. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome ! This is a traditional way of solving this kind of problems.

Comment: Okay, using slack variables my inequality constraints become equality ones. Because of this I should be able to solve the problem using Lagrange. Just to be sure ($y$ = slack variable): will my Lagrange-function become $L(x_i,y_i)$ and I have to derive also the function to $y_i$ ?

Comment: For sure ! Cheers.

Comment: Im currently fiddling with the Langranian to solve a example. Another small question: are there different meanings in linear / nonlinear? Linear as in $ x + y $ and nonlinear as in $ x * y $ for the variable dimension? Or linear as in $ x + y $ and nonlinear as in $ x^2 + x + y + y^2 $ for the exponent dimension?

Comment: I think that terminology will be hard. Just consider if the derivative of the constraint wrt each variable is a constant or a function. Same as for the objective function.